# Is there a way to use Cockpit while UFW is enabled?

Tags: server, apache2, ufw, cockpit

I currently have Ubuntu 20.04 installed. I'm having issues with UFW that are preventing me from using Cockpit. When I try to load IP:9090 into Firefox, it will just continuously try to load with a blank page nonstop. I also had an issues where UFW was preventing me from doing SSH from the terminal, but I did some research online and worked around it with`sudo ufw allow ssh`, but I digress.

I tried doing more online research as for (active) UFW not allowing me to use Cockpit/navigate to IP:9090 in Firefox, but I didn't have much luck with it. I did try installing Apache to see if that would help. I'd used `sudo ufw app list`.  As the list brought up SSH and Apache, I typed `sudo ufw allow 'Apache'` which didn't work, so I typed `sudo ufw allow 'Apache Full'`, which didn't work either. I'm definitely new, so I'm not even 100% sure if messing with Apache was the right direction to begin with. It's just what was recommended when I tried researching this problem online.

[image]

I input `sudo systemctl status cockpit.socket` in the terminal, and it says that it's active (listening).

I'm at a loss as to what to do next. Does anyone have a recommended course of action that I should try?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you confirmed that the Cockpit agent is running?

Comment: Yes, I did input ```sudo systemctl status cockpit.socket``` into the Terminal and it does state that it's active (listening).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cockpit's cockpit-ws component is configured by default to accept connections on port 9090 . This is the port that is documented for a "Web-based System Manager" to listen on. It is also relatively memorable.

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo ufw allow 9090
```